# What parameters should be in abstract method

Tags: java

I have one abstract Class `Client` and 4 children `Client1` `Client2` ...

each of this client line:

```
    response = service.iszr(params);
```

where response and params depends on class

in Class1 this is

```
Client1ResponseType response
Client1params params
```

now I want to add to the abstract class method:

```
  protected abstract void sendRequest(?? response, ?? params);
```

but I dont know what type should be

I try somethink like this:

```
  protected abstract <I, O> void sendRequest(I input, O output);
```

and in children

```
  @Override
  protected <Client1ResponseType, Client1params> void sendRequest(Client1ResponseType input,
      Client1params output) {
    output = service.iszrRobCtiAifo(input);
  }
```

but with no succes. There is compilation error. What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: check out my response, I edited it. Should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the declaration of your abstract class you need to add this:

```
    abstract class Client <I extends SOME_CLASS1, O extends SOME_CLASS2>
```

where SOME_CLASS1 is a subtype of your fist argument and SOME_CLASS2 is a subtype of your second argument, both can be `Object` if you need.

And your abstract method goes like this:

```
    protected abstract void sendRequest(I response, O params);
```

When you extend the class, you need to specify those types like this:

```
    class Client1 extends Client <Client1ResponseType, Client1params>
```

Please let me know if you got any problems.

Comment: hm but problem is response and params are generated class which doesnt extend nothing and I cant edit them co I cannot use     abstract class Client <I extends SOME_CLASS1, O extends SOME_CLASS2>

Comment: Yes you can @hudi, every class extends Object (:

Comment: @hudi Then use `Object` as someone mentioned in the answer, and type-cast it as needed.

Comment: No, that's not the point of this answer, when you extend the abstract class, you will specify those types, so no more type-cast will be needed.

Comment: in `Client1`, `I` will be `Client1ResponseType` and `O` will be `Client1params` as you wanted

Comment: @hudi, I just tested and it works, I'll upload it and you can take a look.

Comment: yes you are right this works. You have nothing to do when u post nice example too ? thx a lot

Comment: You're welcome! What can I do other than this? (x You mean community wiki?

Comment: just one question. Isnt this a little bit overkill generalize class just because of one new method ?

Comment: Well, I don't think so. It really depends on your design, the point is not how many methods you need to generalize, the point is if you really need to generalize that? like, you need to keep some kind of collection of `Client` s for instance, or in some point of your code you need a `Client` object to hold a reference to any `Client#`?

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand fully what actually you are trying to do.

But some way you want to make it generic??

Try **Object**

```
  protected abstract void sendRequest(Object response, Object params);
```

you can extend this variant to other generics like `Object[]`